# How can I install the phpspreadsheet in codeignter version 4

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I have tried to install the package of phpspreadsheet for both way for github and through composer also but I am unable to install
In composer i am trying these command :- composer require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet but its not working
It's basically show these  type of error:-
[InvalidArgumentException]
Package phpoffice/phpspreadsheet has requirements incompatible with your PHP version, PHP extensions and Composer v
ersion:
- phpoffice/phpspreadsheet 1.19.0 requires ext-gd * but it is not present.
And when i am trying directly for github code its files is not in proper way as the requriement
git hub link:- https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`phpoffice/phpspreadsheet v1.19.0` [requires](https://packagist.org/packages/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet#1.19.0) `php: ^7.3 || ^8.0`

1. Check your installed PHP version by running this command `php -v`. Make sure it's greater or equal to `7.3`.
2. Secondly, make sure that the PHP version declaration in the `composer.json` file is also greater or equal to `7.3`. I.e:

```json
        "php": "^7.3 || ^8.0",
```

- If in case your application has dependencies that aren't compatible with PHP version `>= 7.3`, you may want to install a lower version of *phpspreadsheet* i.e `composer require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet "^1.8.0"`  ([requires php: "^5.6|^7.0"](https://packagist.org/packages/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet#1.8.0)) instead of adjusting the PHP version in the file `composer.json`.

3. In addition, if you're using *xampp*, make sure these extensions are enabled in the file *C:\xampp\php\php.ini* **before** attempting to install the library.
   `extension=mbstring`
   `extension=fileinfo`
   `extension=gd`

- Enabling the above extensions means, they **shouldn't** have semicolons (`;`) in front of them.

## Installation

`composer require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet "^1.19.0"`

Comment: Done with all these step and also look at the version but its not working

Comment: @SURAJPANDEY , what error are you getting now?  Please edit your question and share the contents of your `composer.json` file.

Comment: @SURAJPANDEY ,  Also, share the output of this command. `php -v`

Comment: I have solved that error and its perfect install
use command :- composer require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet --ignore-platform-reqs
and then add phpspreadshet File in vendor folder ie. that you have directly extract form github resp :-https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet
and then use these command :- 'PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet' => BASEURL . 'vendor/phpoffice/PhpSpreadsheet',on app/config/autoload
and then use the require files:-
require './vendor/autoload.php';
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;

Comment: Thanks for you kind help -- steven7mwesigwa

Answer (score 0):

What fixed it for me, was `steven7mwesigwa` 3rd point.

```
In addition, if you're using xampp, make sure these extensions are enabled in the file C:\xampp\php\php.ini before attempting to install the library.

extension=mbstring

extension=fileinfo

extension=gd
```

I removed the semicolon in front of the `extension=gd`, and it worked.

Comment: These extension has to been unable during setup of ci4 
Sorry! so that is not a perfect answer